# HashTable Key vs Value Fetch Complexity

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I just read an interview question that asked for the fetching complexity of a hash key vs a hash value. I always figured both to be the same, at O(1 + n/k) (where k is number of buckets). What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a bad question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetching a hash *key* is O(lk) in the length of the key, because you have to hash it, but `n/k` is supposed to be constant for any given hash table. This is usually referred to as O(1) as it does not depend on `n`, but it's not *strictly* O(1) unless the key size is fixed.

But fetching a hash *value* would require iterating through the whole table looking for it, assuming you didn't pre-order it (you can design hash tables which can support binary lookups too for O(log(n)) but this is uncommon).

Comment: So just to clarify, worst case would be O(lk) for hash key fetch, and O(n) for hash value fetch?

Answer (score 2):

A hash value is the initial lookup location.  If the required data is not stored at that index, then the hash key is obtained by iterating until the sought after data is found.